# How to get Liferay custom page attribute list?

Tags: java, liferay

I have created custom fields for **Page entity** in **Liferay** and i tried to get the list of my custom fields in page Details using `custom-attribute-list`:

```
<% 
   Group liveGroup = (Group)request.getAttribute("site.liveGroup"); 
%>
<liferay-ui:custom-attribute-list
    className="<%= Group.class.getName() %>"
    classPK="<%= (liveGroup != null) ? liveGroup.getGroupId() : 0 %>"
    editable="<%= true %>"
    label="<%= true %>"             
/>
```

but i get the Site attribute list.
I treid with `getAttribute("page.liveGroup")` but doesn't work.
What's missing?
How can i get the custom fields list for the page-entity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay page is not of a type `Group` but of a type `Layout`. You should use `Layout.class.getName()` and related `classPK`.